# Modifying list with numbers in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying modify a list. Currently, there is a list with random number and I would like to change the list which creates maximum number of increase between numbers. Maybe I worded badly. For example, if list is `[2,3,1,2,1]`, I would modify into `[1,2,3,1,2]` since 1->2, 2->3 and 1->2 in an increase which gives total of 3 increasing sequence. Any suggestions?

Comment: What the desired result of the following list `[2,3,1,2,1,4,2,2,3,1]` be `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]`?

Answer (score 1):

I would approach your problem with this recursive algorithm. What I am doing is sorting my list, putting all duplicates at the end, and repeating the same excluding the sorted, duplicate-free list.

```
def sortAndAppendDuplicates(l):

    l.sort()
    ll = list(dict.fromkeys(l)) # this is 'l' without duplicates
    i = 0
    while i < (len(ll)-1):
        if list[i] == list[i+1]:
            a = list.pop(i)
            list.append(a)
            i = i - 1
        i = i + 1

    if hasNoDuplicates(l):
        return l
    return ll + sortAndAppendDuplicates(l[len(ll):])

def hasNoDuplicates(l):

     return( len(l) == len( list(dict.fromkeys(l)) ) )


print(sortAndAppendDuplicates([2,3,6,3,4,5,5,8,7,3,2,1,3,4,5,6,7,7,0,1,2,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,4,3,3,5,1,2,1]))

# this would print [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 3, 5, 3, 5]
```